# Why does it suddenly cause an exception to load a dictionary from a LSO object in flash AS3?

Tags: flash, internet-explorer, google-chrome, actionscript, dictionary

Ran into this strange bug developing a web game in Flash CS5.5

When the game starts up it loads player history information from the LSO.  I've been doing it the same way for months now, but for some reason about 10 days ago the following line and other similar ones starting causing exceptions in Chrome and Internet Explorer.  They all have to do with loading a dictionary from an LSO data object.  Does anyone know why this would suddenly start to cause problems now, when it worked fine before?  Since my code and compile setup has been the same for a long time, is it possible that something changed in Chrome or Internet Explorer?

during startup the LSO gets loaded

```
this.lso = SharedObject.getLocal("myLSO");
```

but then this exception happens:

> User exception thrown: TypeError: Error #1034: Type Coercion failed:
>   cannot convert Object@1278ad19 to flash.utils.Dictionary...

which was being caused by this line:

```
this.game.playerHist.completionData=this.lso.data.playerHistory.completionData;
```

the solution that finally worked was to clone the dictionary like this:

```
this.game.playerHist.completionData =
    this.clone(this.lso.data.playerHistory.completionData);
```

using this function, which essentially does the same thing in treating the original object like a dictionary (by getting its keys), but for some reason is doesn't raise an exception:

```
function clone(original:Object):Dictionary {
    var cloned:Dictionary= new Dictionary();
    for(var key:Object in original) {
        cloned[key]=original[key];
    }
    return cloned;
}
```

Also strangely sometimes when a dictionary was loaded without the clone function it worked fine in IE and only raised an exception in Chrome.  Does anyone have any ideas what might be the difference between the 2 browsers, or have any way to explain this?

Answer (score 0):

I think by default flash is limited to storing only the following types in a SharedObject:
Boolean,
int,
uint,
Number,
Object,
Array

To allow it to store other data types you must register an alias like so:

```
flash.net.registerClassAlias('flash.utils.Dictionary', flash.utils.Dictionary);
```

Similarly, I would assume the object types being used as keys in your Dictionary must also be registered for this to work.

See [example](http://www.mark-powell.co.uk/2010/08/save-a-class-as-a-shared-object-with-as3/)